# PHP 5.1 SESSION_START ERROR after 60 Minutes Application RUn

Tags: php, session

I need help about error at my php application. for first time running my application work good. but after 60 minutes my application error at session_start(). **page not found**. I use javascript timer to check Session. is there any issue about sessiont_start().

Comment: First off, welcome to SO. Secondly, we can't do anything without examples of code to solve an issue with a clear answer. Lastly, this is likely a server configuration error and if so, would be better off on Server Fault

Answer (score 0):

check your php.ini
**session.cache_expire.**

the default time is 180 minutes. you can extend your time following as

```
session_cache_expire("minutes");
```

see [manual](http://php.net/session.cache-expire)